# Could not start the Nginx engine: nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog

Tags: node.js, apache, passenger, centos6

I installed passenger standalone on my centos 6 vps and I want to run it behing apache reverse proxy. I have checked the other posted problem and found their solution is not for the standalone...and it concerns ruby on rails which I don't know at all.

The problem is when I start the passenger  `sudo passenger start`     application I am getting this error :

> Could not start the Nginx engine: nginx: [alert] Unable to start the
>   Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error
>   during startup: Unable to start the Passenger core: it seems to have
>   crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1:
>   Unknown error)

The error is speaking of Nginx but I didn't install any..and in passenger standalone installation there is no where it is recommanded for it to work.

I went to check my log file and found things I don't understand :

```
[ N 2017-12-02 06:19:54.7231 24223/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1267 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog... [ E 2017-12-02 06:19:54.7880 24226/T1 age/Sha/Fun/Initialization.cpp:569 ]: *** ERROR: Cannot open /var/www/mainfolder/myapp/passenger.3000.log for writing: Permission denied (errno=13)
     in 'Passenger::VariantMap Passenger::Agent::Fundamentals::initializeAgent(int, char***, const char*, void (*)(int, const char**, Passenger::VariantMap&), void (*)(Passenger::VariantMap&), int)' (Initialization.cpp:538)

[ W 2017-12-02 06:19:55.7969 24223/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:353 ]: Cannot open cleanup PID file /tmp/passenger-standalone.10mxrug/temp_dir_toucher.pid 2017/12/02 06:19:54 [alert] 24220#0: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Passenger core: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error) [ N 2017-12-02 06:21:21.6338 24269/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1267 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog... [ E 2017-12-02 06:21:21.6456 24272/T1 age/Sha/Fun/Initialization.cpp:569 ]: *** ERROR: Cannot open /var/www/mainfolder/myapp/passenger.3000.log for writing: Permission denied (errno=13)
     in 'Passenger::VariantMap Passenger::Agent::Fundamentals::initializeAgent(int, char***, const char*, void (*)(int, const char**, Passenger::VariantMap&), void (*)(Passenger::VariantMap&), int)' (Initialization.cpp:538)

[ W 2017-12-02 06:21:22.6516 24269/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:353 ]: Cannot open cleanup PID file /tmp/passenger-standalone.1pdjhr4/temp_dir_toucher.pid 2017/12/02 06:21:21 [alert] 24266#0: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Passenger core: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error) [ N 2017-12-02 07:01:35.1783 25608/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1267 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog... [ E 2017-12-02 07:01:35.1919 25611/T1 age/Sha/Fun/Initialization.cpp:569 ]: *** ERROR: Cannot open /var/www/mainfolder/myapp/passenger.3000.log for writing: Permission denied (errno=13)
     in 'Passenger::VariantMap Passenger::Agent::Fundamentals::initializeAgent(int, char***, const char*, void (*)(int, const char**, Passenger::VariantMap&), void (*)(Passenger::VariantMap&), int)' (Initialization.cpp:538)

[ W 2017-12-02 07:01:36.1992 25608/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:353 ]: Cannot open cleanup PID file /tmp/passenger-standalone.2zbgfm/temp_dir_toucher.pid 2017/12/02 07:01:34 [alert] 25605#0: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Passenger core: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error)
```

Inside myapp directory I have the Passengerfile.json with the following configuration:

```
{
  // Tell Passenger that this is a Node.js app.
  // Replace "app.js" with your app's entry point file.
  "app_type": "node",
  "startup_file": "app.js",
  // Run the app in a production environment. The default value is "development".
  "environment": "production",
  // Run Passenger on the given port. In this example, we use port 80,
  // the standard HTTP port.
  "port": 3000,
  // Tell Passenger to daemonize into the background.
  "daemonize": true,
  // Tell Passenger to run the app as the given user. Only has effect
  // if Passenger was started with root privileges.
  "user": "mynodeappauser"
  }
```

I need to understand what is blocking the app from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the text of the error: `Cannot open /var/www/mainfolder/myapp/passenger.3000.log for writing: Permission denied`

Make sure your `mynodeappauser` user has permission to create and write to this file.

Comment: Now I am getting this error :
Could not start the Nginx engine:
nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Passenger core: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error)

Comment: Turn up the log level `passenger start --log-level 7` to get more detail, that error isn't very helpful on it's own. (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--log-level-log_level)

Comment: The output of the command sudo passenger start --log-level 7 is : 
Could not start the Nginx engine:
nginx: [warn] 4096 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024
nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Passenger core: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error)                         Also does the passenger standalone depend on nginx? I am using apache I don't get how it connected to nginx.

Comment: My application is finally running thanks @Camden Narzt ... I  tried to reinstall passenger instead of looking for any configuration solution and it worked for me.

Comment: to answer your previous question, yes passenger standalone uses nginx internally, unless you pass the `--engine builtin` flag, which if you use apache in front of passenger you should be doing. (You could also look into mod_passenger to directly integrate passenger into apache).